# Accessing a multi dimensional arrays value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have user a plugin to upload files every thing is working fine know I have to save that uploaded file name into database I need to access the file name

when I do `print_r()` function ;

```
 $files = $data['data'];
        print_r($files);
```

I get

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => ../user/sadiss/_TvJYDCqzP.png
        )

[metas] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date] => Tue, 16 Jun 2015 05:15:43 -0700
                [extension] => png
                [file] => ../user/sadiss/_TvJYDCqzP.png
                [name] => _TvJYDCqzP.png
                [old_name] => 10 PVAs
                [replaced] => 
                [size] => 12914
                [size2] => 12.61 KB
                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image
                        [1] => png
                    )

            )

    )
```

as you can see array has two more arrays `[file]` and meta `[metas]` I want to access `[name]` in `[metas]`

Comment: echo [metas][0][file] use can get the output

Comment: These are the absolute basics of programming, therefore, this question is offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it with:

```
$files['metas'][0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get all the names from the inner array

```
foreach($files as $key=>$val)
{
   if($val == 'metas')
   {
     foreach($val as $innerKey=>$innerVal)
     {
       $file = $innerVal['name'];
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
echo $files['metas'][0]['name'];
```

**Result :**

```
_TvJYDCqzP.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this :

```
$files = $data['data'];

 echo  $fileName = $data['data']['metas'][0]['file'];
```

if you are getting multiple records then do like this:

```
foreach($files['metas']  as $key=>$val){
if($key == 'file'){
echo "File Name: ".$val;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ..if there will be more values in meta's ( like meta[1]) array it will print all the name values ... 
`foreach($data['data']['meta'] as $innerKey=>$innerVal)
{
 echo $filename = $innerVal['name'];
}`

Comment: Do not copy paste from other's answers

Comment: Just copied ur variables BT logic is different